# Will garbage collector recycle an object if the object's type was mapped with the TransientLifetimeManager in Unity?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container, object-lifetime

Will garbage collector recycle an object if the object's type was mapped with the `TransientLifetimeManager` in Unity?

I assume the garbage collector will recycle the object. So, that makes me ask the following question: What is the difference between the `TransientLifetimeManager` and the `ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager` then? Both do not track the object lifetime.

In case the type registered with the `TransientLifetimeManager` won`t get recycled I have another question: Why did developers make such a decision? It seems unreasonable to preserve the type registered with the `TransientLifetimeManager`, since there are might be a lot of them created. And also once the object of the type registered with the `TransientLifetimeManager` is created the reference can be provided by the IoC container to the consumer only once, so, again no point in preserving the reference to the object.

**NOTE**

The question is not related to Unity3D at all. Please, keep it professional and do not edit the question if you do not know what it is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TransientLifetimeManager` does not track lifietime, but it creates new instance per resolve.
`ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager` does not track lifetime and creates only one instance. Container holds only weak reference to object, so after container disposing object will stay alive.

More information in [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff660872(v=pandp.20)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [examples](http://www.tomdupont.net/2013/12/undestanding-unity-lifetime-managers.html).

Comment: `Container holds only weak reference to object, so after container disposing object will stay alive.` See no reasoning behind the sentence at all, please, check it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: So, the main difference between the `TransientLifetimeManager` and the `ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager` is that while the first is created every time the resolve happens, the latter is created only **once** during the first resolve and all the subsequent resolves return the same object. Is it correct?